# ZF2 "Unable to render template" Zend looks in wrong directory

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I've got a strange situation...

After the creation of the ZF2 SkeletonApplication I created an extra Module called Authentication with an AuthController and a LoginAction also in the view directory "authentication/auth" i placed a login.phtml.

When i run the app i get an error

```
Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "authentication/auth/login"; resolver could not resolve to a file
```

The strange thing is that when I place the complete folder "authentication/auth/login.phtml" in the Standard Application Module View Folder it finds it.

So Zend is looking in the wrong directory.

This is my module.config.php (Authentication Module).

```
return array(
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'authentication' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/authentication/login',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Authentication\Controller\Auth',
                    'action'     => 'login',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Authentication\Controller\Auth' => 'Authentication\Controller\AuthController',
    ),
),
'viewmanager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'authentication' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
    )
);
```

This is the AuthController

```
namespace Authentication\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class AuthController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function loginAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complete path cannot be resolved by zf2. The viewManager is using your template pathStack to find the relative view. In your example, the viewManager is looking for this file :
    **DIR** . '/../view/authentication/auth/login.phtml

In other way, you can add to your viewManager a templateMap like this :

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_map' => array(
        'authentication/auth/login' => __DIR__ . '/../view/where/you/want.phtml',
     )
 );
```

Answer (score 2):

change your config:

```
'template_path_stack' => array(
    'authentication' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
),
```

I am guessing you are a level too far back..

If you config is here:

```
Authentication/config/module.config.php
```

then you only want to go back a single level, then into your view directory. Your code would take you back a level higher, into the modules directory.

Comment: Sorry, That was something I tried to force an error, edited it just now.